# Modx Evo: Cannot style table within a TV

Tags: css, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

Wondering if someone knows a way around this: I have a RichText TV that has a table in it. My external CSS, however, does not affect it.

I have used very specific pointers and even given the table an id, but nothing I do seems to change the style. Inline CSS does work, however.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Do you have a live example or a code snippets of the generated code?

Comment: Sure, live example here: http://www.customforklifts.com.au/duplicate-of-heli-forklifts.html - the tables are within the JQuery slider

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking to style table at the bottom (not the one sliding)? From first view, table seems pretty straight forward, your style should apply cleanly, but you have to target the correct element with a CSS rule strong enough to out rules the others. Checkout developer tools to be sure no rule overwrites your. Else, you can try clearing the cache of MODx (this could help if you've edited code - class name, ids, etc), but I'd be surprise your problem come from there.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias, no sorry - it is the tables within the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there may be some css issues as well.
For instance to style the table row you are using:

```
.slideritem .slidertable tr
```

but you should use instead:

```
.slideritem .slidertable tr td
```

Double check your css and the styling should go fine